# How to create the Utah teapot in DirectX 11?

Tags: directx, directx-11

In DirectX 9, we can use the D3DXCreateTeapot function to create a teapot mesh for render, but, it seems D3D 11 has no such function, is there any library or function in D3D11 that can draw a teapot? We usually need a common 3D model to perform some graphics effects and teapot is always the default one.

[Utah teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_teapot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX 11 doesn't provide common geometry anymore.

You can look at this project, which has common geometric primitives (including teapot) and some other bits:

http://directxtk.codeplex.com/